# Change input value from parent component Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, viewchild

I need to change input value for custom value every time I am clicking out of the input. Here is [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bur9qv?file=app/ui-input.component.ts). I tried it with `@ViewChild`, but it works only first time. If I paste something after the first click out of the component - value doesn't change when I clicked again out of the input. Why is this happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use (focus) and (focusout)
like this :

```
<input name="date" type="text" (focus)="focusFunc()" (focusout)="focusOutFunc()">
```

Comment: No, i have a bit complicated logic, it is just simple example. And there i need to handle click outside of the component, because component it is not only input. And btw, i think this wouldn't fix the problem that i described